How to change runtime the route controller class of Slim4?
I'm working with Slim4 and I need to create website "variants" based on the URL hostname.
I already completed this task using a middleware:
final class SiteSelectorMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface{
    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        $host=$request->getUri()->getHost();
        $request = $request->withAttribute('host', $host);
        //SOME OTHER STUFF
        return $handler->  handle($request);
    }
}

This will pass the hostname as attribute, selects different Twig resources for templates and so on.
But now I need also to add some little changes to controllers logics and I don't want to do something like this in my controllers:
class MyAction{
    public function get(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response): ResponseInterface
    {
            if($host=="variantsite") {
                //do something
            }else{
                //do something else
            }
    }
}

I would prefer to use a new Controller class that extends the original one.
class SubClassMyAction extends MyAction{
    public function get(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response): ResponseInterface
    {
        //do something
        return parent::get($request,$response);
    }
}

My routes are defined like this:
return function (App $app) {
    $app->get('/mypage', MyAction::class. ':get');
    $app->post('/mypage', MyAction::class. ':post');
}

Is there any way to alter the associated controller runtime in a middleware to change on the fly the previous settings to
return function (App $app) {
    $app->get('/mypage', SubClassMyAction::class. ':home');
    $app->post('/mypage', SubClassMyAction::class. ':home');
}


The routing definitions itself cannot be changed afterwards, but could be defined dynamically during the load process.
